# Cant find ReportingService2010

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, namespaces

I have a Reportviewer inside my project(wpf)and i need to populate a treeView with All the reports contained on a SSRS server,to do that i need to be able to access the server to read all the items and filter out the reports.

The only way i have found to access ReportingService2010(needed) is by having a Web reference, which is not allowed (My architect doesnt want web references)

Can somebody please tell me which namespace i need to 'using' to be able to get reportingService2010 ?

Comment: To anybody wondering, my Architect is very strict that he does NOT want a web reference.
thus i cant use it.

Comment: yeah, I'm not really sure what you're trying to ask.  are you trying to create a new report project in visual studios?

Comment: @DForck42 I need to call ReportingService2010 WIHOUT using a web reference...I have been going through namespaces for hours just trying to get ReportingService2010 so i can read the reports that are on the SSRS server.

Comment: so... you need to render a report inside of a webpage, or...?

Comment: is this what you're looking for?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.aspx

Comment: @DForck42 I have a Reportviewer inside my project(wpf)...But i need to populate a treeView with All the reports contained on a SSRS server....to do that i need to be able to access the server to read all the items and filter out the reports...the only way i have found to access ReportingService2010(needed) is by having a Web reference, which is not allowed (My architect doesnt want web references)

Comment: ok, that's very important information.  you should edit that into your question.

Comment: @DForck42 will do

Answer (score 0):

If SQL Server Reporting Services is in Native mode (I am unsure quite how the database works in SharePoint Mode), you can query the Catalog table in the Reporting Services database (by default named ReportServer) to get all of the information you need.

My local report server isn't quite set up at the moment, but here are the important pieces you'll need:

```
select
    itemID,
    ParentID,
    [Path],
    [Type]
from dbo.[Catalog]
```

If I remember correctly, TYPE = 1 are folders, TYPE = 2 are reports, but I'm unsure and currently unable to test.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you have .netframework >= 4.6.1

2) Run command prompt as administrator

3) cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools

4) Generate class:
wsdl /proxyusername:**Username** /proxypassword:**Password** -out:Reportingservice2010.cs http://**Servername**/Reportserver/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl

Additional) Run wsdl /? for help
            Files will output in:
            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools

5) Add the .cs file to your project